# Tastypie POST XML returns json

Tags: xml, django, json, post, tastypie

I have a resource that needs to accept POST requests serialized as XML.
The resource needs to return the full object upon post. Therefore i set

```
always_return_data = True
```

I am able to successfully post data but the response is always JSON.
I tried setting the serializer to be XML only, by stating

```
serializer = Serializer(formats=['xml'])
```

but i still get the response in JSON.

Has anyone seen this and solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the answer was pretty easy and obvious…

Simply add

```
?format=xml
```

to the URL (even when using POST) and the response and content type will be XML as well